# Ruby on Rails: Getting an AdapterNotSpecified for a website although it's been defined

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx

When I try to run the following code

```
$ rake RAILS_ENV=sharetribe_production ts:start
```

I get the following error,

```
my-MacBook-Pro:sharetribe Frostzone$ rake RAILS_ENV=sharetribe_production ts:start
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter
/Users/Frostzone/sharetribe/config/environment.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => ts:start => environment
```

While my database.yml looks like the one below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqOQi.png

The adapter **is** defined as mysql2. I'm currently following the instructions provided here to setup a demo sharetribe website.

https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe

Answer (score 1):

Your command should be:

`rake RAILS_ENV=production ts:start`

Your database.yml file defines the `production` environment, not the `sharetribe_production` environment.

Answer (score 0):

specify `sharetribe_production` configuration in `database.yml` this may help you.